# Input type hidden occupying space within IE6 & 7

Tags: input, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I am using an input tag to retrieve some user information. This user information is not required to be rendered by the browser so I have give it a class with 'display: none' applied.

IE6 and 7 are still rendering the space the input occupies but without rendering the content, the same way 'visibility: hidden' would work.

Are there any other ways to get IE6 and 7 to completely ignore the input?

Answer (score 1):

If input hidden values are inside table then they are rendered without `TR` and `TD`; so adding them inside `TR`, `TD` and setting `tr { display: none }` has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the input type="hidden"?